# Log4J ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, pom.xml

I am receiving error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger` from the console. The SpringBoot has been launched successfully and there are no errors in Build Path.

Other logging functionalities are working fine, I declare the logger as this:

```
import org.jboss.logging.Logger
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CustomerController.class);
```

and the console is showing the logs for

`LOGGER.info("Executing [POST] request to retrieveCustomerResponse()");`

I also have the `log4j.xml` file in my root directory containing the basic settings.

and here is my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want to use the Log4j logger why are you importing the JBoss one?

Comment: Which Version of `log4j-api` you are using?

Comment: @Brenin because the `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` class has no `Logger.getLogger([class]);`

Comment: @Jens I am using 2.10.0

Comment: @RanielleCanlas Use "LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerController.class);" instead.

Comment: log4j2 has a different api: import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

Comment: Here an example: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/java-logging/slf4j-with-log4j2.html

Comment: @Jens Thanks for the recommendation of log4j2, but I am maintaining a legacy web service, I'll consider upgrading the logging library once I finished refactoring everything. Thanks.

Comment: @RanielleCanlas log4j2 == log4j 2.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `org.slf4j.Logger` and `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` create the logger object as 
`private static final Logger LOGGER LogerFactory.getLogger(YourClass.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```